# WPF Datagrids slow when using Auto column sizes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

When I expand the Expander in the code below, the application becomes very sluggish and takes 2-3 seconds to respond to resize/move events triggered by the user.  If I set the second column to  `<ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>` response time remains optimal.  What am I missing here? (I'm need the UI as per below but without the sluggishness)

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Toolbar .. />
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding collection1}" .. />
    <Expander Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding collection2}" .. />
    </Expander>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

FYI: I suspect Row Virtualization is not being used when Width=Auto is set and DataGridRow objects are being created for the entire bound data source...

**UPDATE**
The following also does not remove the sluggishness;

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition />
  <ColumnDefinition Width={Binding ElementName=expander, Path=Width} />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
..
<Expander Name="expander" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding collection2}" Width="300" .. />
</Expander>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you set the `ColumnWidth` to `Auto`, the column width will be calculated depending on the content, here, the dataGrid. So you will have the second column very large (even though you might not see it depending on your layout) and the dataGrid's columns will all be drawn every time.

So basically, you loose the benefits of `columnVirtualization` (not `rowVirtualization`).

This is the same reason why you should never put a `DataGrid` into a `ScrollViewer`.

**Solution**
 
Set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` on your grid

if this does not work, you might have to take care of the resizing yourself, no real option there.

Comment: aw crap, spoke to soon (had tagged as answer).  the sluggishness is non-existent when the datagrid inside the expander has minimal rows whether IsVirtualizing is set on the grid or not.  When that datagrid has, say, 100 rows and IsVirtualizing is set the sluggishness returns.  Strange considering both datagrids are showing scrollbars.

Comment: ah, if the DGs are showing scrollbars, it indeed means you should have the column/row virtualization working, so this will not help. Your edit makes indeed no difference, since even without the binding, the width of the grid's column is based on its content (so your code is actually redundant with what WPF already does). I'll try to think more about your issue and make some tests if I have 5 min today